# Open the Results of Autocomplete in Fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, fancybox

I have the following autocomplete searchbox code

```
$("#searchbox").autocomplete({
            source: function(request,response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { term: request.term },
                    url: "/Settings/Find?searchString="+request.term,
                    success: function(data) {
                        response($.map(data,function(item) {
                            return { label: item.Name ,value:  item.Type, ID: item.ID};
                        }

                        ))
                                    }
                })
            },
            messages: {
                noResults: "No Results",results: "Results"
            },
        select: function(e, ui) {
         window.location.assign('/Item/Details/'+ui.item.ID);                 
       }
          },   


    });
```

When the user clicks on the autocompleted items, I redirect them to the detail page of the item using this

```
window.location.assign('/Item/Details/'+item.ID);
```

Now, I want to display the details of the item in a fancybox without redirect the user to another page. So when the user clicks on the autocompleted results, a fancybox opens up with the details of the selected item.

Here is the fancybox code That i would like to call.

```
$('.fancyboxdisplay').fancybox({
                fitToView: false,                
                autoSize: false,
                closeClick: false,
                width: '550px',
                height:'680px',             
                padding: 15,                 
                closeBtn:true,
                'afterClose': function() {
                    window.location.reload();
                },

            });
```

I looked everywhere for a possible solution but i can't figure it out. Can you please help !

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your `select` setting, try replacing `window.location.assign` by the fancybox script like :

```
select: function (e, ui) {
    // window.location.assign('/Item/Details/' + ui.item.ID);
    $.fancybox({
        href: '/Item/Details/' + ui.item.ID,
        type: "iframe",
        fitToView: false,
        autoSize: false,
        closeClick: false,
        width: 550,
        height: 680,
        padding: 15,
        closeBtn: true,
        afterClose: function () {
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

It's assumed you have previously loaded fancybox js and css files